# How to structure tests where one test is another test's setup?

Tags: testing

I'm **integration** testing a system, by using only the public APIs. I have a test that looks something like this:

```
def testAllTheThings():
  email = create_random_email()
  password = create_random_password()

  ok = account_signup(email, password)
  assert ok
  url = wait_for_confirmation_email()
  assert url
  ok = account_verify(url)
  assert ok

  token = get_auth_token(email, password)
  a = do_A(token)
  assert a
  b = do_B(token, a)
  assert b
  c = do_C(token, b)

  # ...and so on...
```

Basically, I'm attempting to test the entire "flow" of a single transaction. Each step in the flow depends on the previous step succeeding. Because I'm restricting myself to the external API, I can't just go poking values into the database.

So, either I have one really long test method that does `A; assert; B; assert; C; assert...", or I break it up into separate test methods, where each test method needs the results of the previous test before it can do its thing:

```
def testAccountSignup():
  # etc.
  return email, password

def testAuthToken():
  email, password = testAccountSignup()
  token = get_auth_token(email, password)
  assert token
  return token

def testA():
  token = testAuthToken()
  a = do_A(token)
  # etc.
```

I think this smells. Is there a better way to write these tests?

Answer (score 11):

If this test is intended to run *frequently*, your concerns would rather be focused on how to present test results in a way *convenient* to those expected to work with these results.

From this perspective, `testAllTheThings` raises a huge red flag. Imagine someone running this test every hour or even more frequently (against buggy codebase of course, otherwise there would be no point to re-run), and seeing every time all the same `FAIL`, without a clear indication of what stage failed.

Separate methods look much more appealing, because results of re-runs (assuming steady progress in fixing bugs in code) could look like:

```
    FAIL FAIL FAIL FAIL
    PASS FAIL FAIL FAIL -- 1st stage fixed
    PASS FAIL FAIL FAIL
    PASS PASS FAIL FAIL -- 2nd stage fixed
    ....
    PASS PASS PASS PASS -- we're done
```

---

Side note, in one of my past projects, there were so many re-runs of *dependent* tests that users even began complaining about not willing to see repeated expected failures at later stage "triggered" by a failure at the earlier one. They said this garbage makes it harder to them to analyze test results *"we know already that the rest will fail by test design, don't bother us repeating"*.

As a result, test developers were eventually forced to extend their framework with additional `SKIP` status and add a feature in test manager code to abort execution of dependent tests and an option to drop `SKIP`ped test results from the report, so that it looked like:

```
    FAIL -- the rest is skipped
    PASS FAIL -- 1st stage fixed, abort after 2nd test
    PASS FAIL
    PASS PASS FAIL -- 2nd stage fixed, abort after 3rd test
    ....
    PASS PASS PASS PASS -- we're done
```

Comment: as i read it, it sounds like it would've been better to actually write a testAllTheThings, but with clear reporting of where it failed.

Comment: @Javier _clear reporting of where it failed_ sounds nice in theory, but in my practice, whenever tests are executed frequently, those working with these strongly prefer seeing dumb PASS-FAIL _tokens_

Answer (score 8):

I'd separate the testing code from the setup code. Perhaps:

```
# Setup
def accountSignup():
    email = create_random_email()
    password = create_random_password()

    ok = account_signup(email, password)
    url = wait_for_confirmation_email()
    verified = account_verify(url)
    return email, password, ok, url, verified

def authToken():
    email, password = accountSignup()[:2]
    token = get_auth_token(email, password)
    return token

def getA():
    token = authToken()
    a = do_A()
    return a

def getB():
    a = getA()
    b = do_B()
    return b

# Testing
def testAccountSignup():
    ok, url, verified = accountSignup()[2:]
    assert ok
    assert url
    assert verified

def testAuthToken():
    token = authToken()
    assert token

def testA():
    a = getA()
    assert a

def testB():
    b = getB()
    assert b
```

Remember, all random information that is generated *must* be included in the assertion in case it fails, otherwise your test may not be reproducible. I might even record the random seed used. Also any time a random case does fail, add that specific input as a hard-coded test to prevent regression.

Comment: +1 for you!  Tests are code, and DRY applies as much in testing as it does in production.

Answer (score 2):

Not *much* better, but you can at least separate setup code from asserting code. Write a separate method that tells the entire story step by step, and take a parameter controlling how many steps it should take. Then each test can say something like `simulate 4` or `simulate 10` and then assert whatever it tests.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I might not get the Python syntax right here by "air coding", but I guess you get the idea: you can implement a general function like this:

```
def asserted_call(create_random_email,*args):
    result=create_random_email(*args)
    assert result
    return result
```

which will allow you to write your tests like this:

```
  asserted_call(account_signup, email, password)
  url = asserted_call(wait_for_confirmation_email)
  asserted_call(account_verify,url)
  token = asserted_call(get_auth_token,email, password)
  # ...
```

Of course, it is debatable if the loss in readability of this approach is worth to use it, but it reduces the boilerplate code a little bit.