# Unit Testing method with multiple steps

Tags: unit-testing, testing, refactoring

I have a validation method like this

```
def validate(a, b, c, d, e, f): Boolean = {
  val rs1 = check1(a, b)
  val rs2 = check2(c, d)
  val rs3 = check3(e, f)

  rs1 && rs2 && rs3
}
```

I have tests for all of the smaller methods `check1`, `check2`, and `check3` and I want to test the big method `validate` also. But to test it, I imagine I have to write tests for all of the cases like:

- all 3 checks succeed
- `check1` fails
- `check2` fails
- ...

not to mention I will have to provide suitable sets of parameters (a, b, ...).

So what is the best practice for this situation or should I just skip testing the `validate` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to structure tests where one test is another test's setup?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/221766/how-to-structure-tests-where-one-test-is-another-tests-setup)

Comment: @gnat Not a duplicate: This question is about testing of *methods* that consist of multiple steps, whereas the linked question is about *tests* that consist of multiple steps.

Comment: @amon I think answers over there cover this, but if you prefer closer looking question, there is [How should I test the functionality of a function that uses other functions in it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225323/how-should-i-test-the-functionality-of-a-function-that-uses-other-functions-in-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test things that could go wrong. So maybe, writing tests for this method would not have much value. It is very simple code, and unlikely to be incorrect. The most likely source of errors is that you are passing the wrong arguments to the check() functions. If you are using a statically typed language, that risk is already reduced.

Note that a single test case (regardless of validation result) is sufficient to provide 100% statement, branch, and path coverage for this implementation of the validation() function when viewed in isolation. However, it does not provide full condition coverage. So writing at least one test case may be desirable. Maybe adding a second test case would also be good, so that you have one successful and one failing validation result.

Beyond that, testing for 100% condition coverage takes increasing amounts of effort for decreasing value. Unless correctness of the method is extremely important (e.g. a failure could cause permanent harm to users and/or would be very costly) this doesn't seem important. To test this method comprehensively, it may be desirable to rewrite your tests of `checkX()` functions as tests of the `validate()` function. This may result in less total effort than writing 3+1 additional tests where you have one test where all checks succeed, and one test per check where that check fails. Also, some people dislike white-box techniques like creating test cases to reach some coverage goal instead of using test cases to express requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tests for all of the smaller methods `check1`, `check2`, and `check3`...

That is the cause of your current problems. `check1` etc are implementation details of `validate`, so should only be tested via testing `validate`. So change those existing tests to use `validate`. That gives you that "*suitable sets of parameters (a, b, ...)*".

All that's then left to do is to test that it only validates when all checks pass.

Comment: Your point makes sense but if `check1` will be used in other places (potentially) then shouldn't I keep testing `check1`?

Comment: @MinhThai, you are testing `check1`, via `validate`. If it's used elsewhere too, then test it via those places, too.

Answer (score -2):

I think that this `Validate()` method is potentially violating the Single Responsibility Principle. According to the SRP, "A class should have one reason to change". Here, we have three reasons to change. Thus, we are violating SRP. I think that's your main problem here.

To refactor this, I would extract `check1()` `check2()` and `check3()` into their own classes, unit test them separately, then inject them into the main validator class. After doing that, I would mock out `Check1Validator`, `Check2Validator`, and `Check3Validator`. The only thing to test now would be the invalid input of `validate()`, and the condition `rs1 && rs2 && rs3.`

Comment: I understand your setup but wouldn't that be the same situation? We still have `validate` receiving `(a, b, c...)` then calls 3 checks then finally do `rs1 && rs2 && rs3`.
There must be always a place where we have to call those 3 checks and merge their results right?

Comment: This answer can be a good approach – but if you inject the check functions, you are introducing another point of fragility. Now we need to ensure that we are injecting the correct checks at runtime. Also, I don't think a single `validate()` method that calls various helper functions is a violation of the SRP.

Comment: @MinhThai, Not if you mock out the the checks. By mocking out, I mean you can use a mocking library to return a dummy value for `check1()`, `check2()`, and `check3()` whenever they are called. Then, you can test that the three validation methods were called properly with the right parameters, and what `Validate()` does with their return values. You don't care about testing them, because you are testing them separately.